# how to make angular links work without starting from root URL?

Tags: angular, routes

I need to create on-demand URLs like these

```
mysite.com/link1
mysite.com/link2
mysite.com/link3
...
```

I prefer to use angular project but at last, I ended up in such these URLs :

```
mysite.com/#/Link1
mysite.com/#/Link2
...
```

How can I remove the # and please pay attention to the problem that these URLs should be sent by email so the user can click on them?

Comment: Can you share app.module code?

Comment: What do you mean create "on demand URL"? usually the routes are defined when you build the app, so each route has a component it routes to (or child route). could you please provide more details on what you are trying to do?

Comment: please update you code by including routing configs.

Comment: @BinaraThambugala there is no special code just a fresh Angular CLI project. After you create it just add a new component and a custom root for it. if you serve the app and enter the custom route URL nothing will happen.

Comment: When I use ng serve it works but when I build and upload the dist folder in a real host on internet it doesn't work.